# 405 error{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am using the following code in my interface and using webapi service.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET")]
bool IsPaymentGatewayExitsForTenant(string tenantSlugName, string productCode);
```

I am running locally and testing the service using rest client

```
api/PaymentGatewayService/IsPaymentGatewayExitsForTenant?tenantSlugName=KPN&productCode=POSS
```

But I am getting the following errror `enter code here`

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."} `enter code here`
```

Any help would be appeciated.

Comment: What is the base class of your Controller? Please show some more code.

Comment: @markus ApiController

Answer (score 5):

Could you please decorate yout controller class method "`IsPaymentGatewayExitsForTenant`" with "`HttpGet`" attribute

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
bool IsPaymentGatewayExitsForTenant(string tenantSlugName, string productCode)
{
   // your code goes here
}
```

hopes this works

Comment: @madhu On StackOverflow, if someone suggests an answer and the answer fixes the problem you were having, please click the grey check mark to the left of the proposed answer. For more information, please look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.